# Ground force on free falling object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-fall

Let a body be falling freely from height $h$ to the ground. Can we express the reactionary force $F$ acting on the body from the ground as a function of $h$, i.e. $F=F(h)$? (My attempt contains also the time $\Delta{t}$, which I supposed is needed for the force to act. Can we avoid it?)

Comment: Hi SK_ , you mention an attempt. You're more likely to get help here if you explicitly share what you tried on your own in your question (you may edit it).

Comment: No, dependence on $\Delta t$ cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can express the total impulse (change in momentum) that the object experiences when it hits the ground as a function of the drop height $h$ as follows.

Impact speed is $v_{\rm imp} = \sqrt{2 g h}$ so the total impulse to stop the object from moving is

$$ J = m v_{\rm imp} = m \sqrt{2 g h} \tag{1}$$

The impulse is developed by some force curve $F(t)$ as function of time, and the impulse is the area under the curve over a finite time slice $\Delta t > 0$. $$J = \int_0^{\Delta t} F(t)\,{\rm d} t \tag{2}$$

Depending on the materials and geometry of the system, the force maximum might be small or very large.

For example dropping on a marble floor, the impulse develops over a very short period of time $\Delta t \ll 1$ and the peak of the force curve $F(t)$ must be very high to net the same impulse $J$ calculated in (1)

But dropping on a trampoline where $\Delta t \approx 1$ then peak force should be much lower for the impulse in (1).

The simplest approximation for $F(t)$ is that of the top half of a cosine curve $$ F(t) = F_{\rm max} \cos \left ( \tfrac{\pi t}{\Delta t} \right) \tag{3}$$ which results when the contact force is linearly proportional to the penetration depth $\delta$ according to Hook's law $$F = -k \delta$$